# ASP.NET JSON response without web service

Tags: asp.net, json

I've got an ASP.NET based website that already has the necessary hooks into my back-end database and I want to write something *really* simple to return a small bit of JSON based on a URL parameter.
So, for example:

```
http://example.com/JSON/GetInfo.aspx?prodID=1234
```

And it would return some JSON with product details for the given ID.

I conceptually know how to do this from *any* ASPX page but I'm wondering if this is the *right* way to do it? (Assuming I would just be writing JSON back out to the response instead of HTML)

I don't need (or want) a full on .NET web service, just something that I could call from other pages on my site as well as one of our applications with a GET request to retrieve the desired info.

In visual studio, when I'm adding a new file what type should I use?

Comment: For this I would use a generic handler (.ashx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a [Generic Web Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx) for this. It's a lightweight web component that you can call from any client code on your site.

Your url would looks like this

```
http://example.com/JSON/GetInfo.ashx?prodID=1234
```

Comment: I've used this approach plenty of times, it works great. Remember to add the reference to your web config though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @asawyer: There is no need to register anything on web.config for his scenario ;) Just need to create the handler and use it.

Comment: Is there really a benefits in this approach versus a simple SVC file that describe a restful web service? Or compared to a ASP.Net Web API Project?

Comment: @Steve B: the main advantage I see over those methods  you mention is simplicity. It's extremelly simple to implement a web handler inside an existing asp.net web forms project.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi That's interesting, in my projects using this technique I've always needed to register the module.

Comment: That's perfect. Didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Look into to ASP.Net Web Methods

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't an ordinary .aspx file do this?

```
string s= "{\"data\":\"test\"}";
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(s);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your aspx page "GetInfo.aspx"
In your Page_Load :

```
string myID = request.QueryString["prodID"];
string myJson = "";

//Fill your JSON with database, ...

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(myJson);
Response.End();
```

That will returning your JSON